# How to retrieve firebase documents missing a field using runQuery and the IN operator?

Tags: firebase, rest, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

This is my http POST requst body...

```
{
"structuredQuery": {
    "select": {
        "fields": [
            {
                "fieldPath": "name"
            },
            {
                "fieldPath": "taxId"
            },
            {
                "fieldPath": "mailingAddress"
            }
        ]
    },
    "from": [
        {
            "collectionId": "orgs"
        }
    ],
    "where": {
        "fieldFilter": {
            "field": {
                "fieldPath": "orgId"
            },
            "op": "IN",
            "value": {
                "arrayValue": {
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "stringValue": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "nullValue": null
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It fails to return orgs where the orgId field is completely missing from the document.  It correctly includes orgs where the orgId field is present and equal to empty string. This is accessing a Cloud Firestore db.

Comment: As a workaround, you can, of course, also retrieve all the documents and then sort out in which ones the field is completely missing... but that costs more resources. I've run into this problem multiple times, when I've forgotten something and I just want to add it to the documents where it's missing!... They should really invent such a query. It's needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the way Firestore indexes data, it is not possible to query for documents for which a certain field "is completely missing from the document": the field needs to exist in order for the Firestore index to take it into account. More details on the indexing mechanism in the following [official video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ofux_4c94FI&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ&index=2).

You may store an empty value in this field, as you mention in your question.